# How to 'subtract' one string from another?

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

Suppose I have the following two strings:

```
var value = "1-000-111";
var mask = " -   -";
```

I want to *subtract* the `mask` from the `value`. In other words I want something like this:

```
var output = subtract(value, mask);
// output should be 1000111
```

What is the best way to implement `subtract()`? I have written this, but that doesn't seem elegant to me.

```
function subtract(value, mask) {
    while (mask.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
        var idx = mask.indexOf('-');
        value = value.substr(0, idx) + value.substr(idx + 1);
        mask = mask.substr(0, idx) + mask.substr(idx + 1);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Does JavaScript have something built-in to accomplish this? Note that, the masking characters are not limited to `-` (dash), but can be other characters as well, like `+`. But in a given case, the masking character can only be either `-` or `+`, which can therefore be sent to the `subtract()` function, which makes handling different masking character trivial. Also, the masking characters will be in arbitrary positions.

Any language-agnostic answers are also welcome.

Comment: could the mask have other characters as hyphens to eliminate?

Comment: Your solution assumes all masks will use `-` is that the case?

Comment: No, mask may contain other characters as well. Also, masking characters may be in arbitrary positions.

Comment: Does the position of the characters you want to remove matter? Does the number of characters to remove differ?

Comment: I'm assuming `value.replace(/-/g '');` doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm That's right. I only want to replace dashes that correspond to the mask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the value string and filter the characters which are unequal to the character at the same position of the mask string.

Then join the array for a new string.

```js
function subtract(value, mask) {
    return value.split('').filter(function (a, i) {
        return a !== mask[i];
    }).join('');
}

console.log(subtract("1-000-111", " -   -"));
console.log(subtract("foo1-000-111", "foo -   -"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through value and check if the corresponding value in `mask` is not `-`

```js
    var value = '1-000-111';
    var mask  = ' -   -';
    
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i += 1) {
        if (mask[i] !== '-') {
            result += value[i];
        }
    }
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mask can be any characters if you iterate through each character of value and compare to same position in mask:

Example using Array#reduce() on split() value

```js
var value = "1-000-111";
var mask = " -   -";

var unmasked  = value.split('').reduce((a,c,i) => (mask[i] === c) ? a : a+c);

console.log(unmasked )
```